# Difference between boto and boto3 in aws python aws, related to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, path, boto3, boto, deprecated

Aws release a note for S3 path deprecation https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/ . In the Documentation, they assure that AWS sdk will be guaranteed except for some problems with the names, if the SDK is the latest version. Now the problem is that AWS has 2 python sdk, boto and boto3. i'm sure that the boto3 will have no problems related to the bucket path, but for the boto i haven't found anything about it. Is boto updated together with boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [github of boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/develop):

> Going forward, API updates and all new feature work will be focused on Boto3.

So boto is no longer getting any API updates nor features. If you check the linked github page, the last commit was over 1 year ago. So its likely that the S3 path changes won't be reflected in boto.

Comment: So with boto i can keep using the path-style method?

Comment: Maybe. But is it worth using a library which does not get any security updates, bug fixes nor will be able to use new aws services and other changes?